# APDU Select Application RETURN SW 6982

Tags: select, smartcard, emv

Im testing a dummy card with specific software for testing developed (not by me), but I'm getting this SW after a Select application command

```
Command: 00A4040007A000000003101000
Status Word: 6982 - Security status not satisfied
```

Then, the GPO command returns 6985, as follows:

```
Command: 80A8000002830000
Status: 6985 - Conditions of use not satisfied
```

can you help to know what it's happening with dummy card.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have Visa application on this dummy card? While you did not select payment application there is no reason to do GPO.

Comment: I think the card was erased, but i dont know if it is possible, because the commands are:

Filter candidate applications
APDU Select Application A0000000031010 - Command: 00A4040007A000000003101000
Status: 6982 - Security status not satisfied

Then GPO is exeucted as follows:


Command: 80A8000002830000
Status: 6985 - Conditions of use not satisfied

This is the flow in card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about a contactless card: the first step in the protocol needs to be a "SELECT 2PAY.SYS.DDF01" (00A404000E325041592E5359532E444446303100) command.

In response to this command the card will send you a list of application IDs (AIDs) that it supports. Your command 
"00A4040007A000000003101000" is asking the card to run app A0000000031010 (which is Visa). So you should double check that this AID is actually one that the cards sends to you as one it supports.

If it is an AID that the card sends to you and you are still getting a 6982 error when trying to select that AID then the card is not EMV compliant.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is clearly wrong - where the author wrote it is a contactless card? The AID is not contactless specific, in fact the AID itself is one byte shorter.

Comment: Yes, Michal is quite right. I assumed that the OP was talking about a contactless card, when this wasn't actually stated.